# How to conditionally nest elements in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Is there any way to do this kind of conditional nesting with Vue?
(Apparently `<component is="template">` outputs a non parsed `<template>` tag into the DOM but does not render anything)

```html
<component :is="condition ? 'div' : 'template'">
    <!-- 2 elements here -->
</component>
```

The purpose is to avoid unneeded markup or repeating my 2 elements code twice in a v-if v-else.

Also having a sub component with the 2 elements would not help as Vue components need only 1 root, so a wrapper would be needed there too.

What I am looking for is an equivalent to:

```html
<div v-if="condition">
    <span>element 1</span>
    <span>element 2</span>
</div>
<template v-else>
    <span>element 1</span>
    <span>element 2</span>
</template>
```

but without rewriting twice the span elements.

(Also posted it on Vue.js forum https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-conditionally-nest-elements/95384)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: But even with `component is` you would be rendering two separate modules.
Dynamic components right?
So how does that reduce the additional mark up.
It is just that they are in separate files?

Comment: @UtsavPatel, sorry I don't understand your question, maybe have a look at  https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-conditionally-nest-elements/95384 to have more details on what I want to do. :)

Comment: @antoni [This post](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/conditionally-render-parent-element/9324/5) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Vue 2:

There is no straight forward solution to this using Vue 2, but you can use [`Functional Components`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) for this purpose, as functional components do not have the single-root limitation.

So first, create a `my-span` functional component which will be rendered in DOM with multiple nodes like:

```
<span>element 1</span>
<span>element 2</span>
```

using:

```
Vue.component('my-span', {
  functional: true,
  render: function (createElement, context) {
    const span1 = createElement('span', 'element 1');
    const span2 = createElement('span', 'element 2');
    return [span1, span2]
  },
})
```

You can create as many nodes you want, with any element you want and simply return that as an array.

In Vue 2.5.0+, if you are using single-file components, template-based functional components can be declared with:

```
<template functional>
</template>
```

Next, create a component just to wrap the `<my-span>` above like:

```
Vue.component('my-div', {
  template: '<div><my-span /></div>'
})
```

Then using Vue’s `<component>` element with the `is` special attribute, we can dynamically switch between the `<my-div>` and `<my-span>` components like:

```
<component :is="condition ? 'my-div' : 'my-span'"></component>
```

This will result in the desired behaviour you are looking for. You can also inspect the rendered DOM to verify this.

**Working Demo:**

```js
Vue.component('my-span', {
  functional: true,
  render: function (createElement, context) {
    const span1 = createElement('span', 'element 1');
    const span2 = createElement('span', 'element 2');
    return [span1, span2]
  },
})

Vue.component('my-div', {
  template: '<div><my-span /></div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data: {
    condition: true
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.condition = !this.condition;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#myApp{padding:20px}
#myApp div{padding:10px;border:2px solid #eee}
#myApp span{padding:5px;margin:5px;display:inline-flex}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button><br>
  <component :is="condition ? 'my-div' : 'my-span'"></component>
</div>
```

---

### Using Vue 3:

In Vue 3, it would ve very easy to implement as we can have multiple root nodes in Vue 3, as you can see `MySpan` component has a template with multiple spans:

```
const MySpan = { template: '<span>element 1</span><span>element 2</span>' };
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const MySpan = { template: '<span>element 1</span><span>element 2</span>' };
const MyDiv = { 
  components: { MySpan },
  template: '<div><my-span /></div>' 
};

const App = {
  components: { MyDiv, MySpan },
  setup() {
    const condition = ref(true);
    const toggle = () => {
      condition.value = !condition.value;
    };
    return { condition, toggle };
  }
};

createApp(App).mount("#myApp");
```

```css
#myApp{padding:20px}
#myApp div{padding:10px;border:2px solid #eee}
#myApp span{padding:5px;margin:5px;display:inline-flex}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button><br>
  <component :is="condition ? 'my-div' : 'my-span'"></component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @palash. I am looking forward to using Vue 3.